# Two Navigation Controllers- navigate from last to first viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Navigationcontroller-->A(viewController)-->B(viewcontroller)-->TabBarController-->NavigationController-->C(tableviewcontroller)-->D viewcontroller.

How could I go back from D viewcontroller to the A viewController

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[yourNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

where yourNavigationController - is your first navigation controller.

Comment: if you see. tabBar presents navigationController, so when we access navController from D, it will not give the first navigationController but the second one

Comment: I have wrote `yourNavigationController`. Not `self.navigationController`. Have you seen it?

Comment: @casillas, was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationController *nav=(UINavigationController*) self.view.window.rootViewController;
[nav setViewControllers:@[[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]] animated:YES];
```

or

```
UINavigationController *nav=(UINavigationController*) self.view.window.rootViewController;
[nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Why have you decided that required navController is rootViewController ?